# Why can't you see up and down votes per person at Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, down-votes, users, up-votes

On the StackExchange sites you can click on any user and see the number of up and down votes they've placed.

On Area 51 you can't.

Why is that?

**See follow up question:** [Area 51 should also display up and down votes per person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75372/area-51-should-also-display-up-and-down-votes-per-person)

Comment: If you're going to fork the feature request as its own question, this should probably be tagged [support] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on a slightly different code base.

It was forked a while back to allow for "not a good example" or "meh" votes as well as the usual "up" and "down" which had been re-purposed for "great on topic" and "great off topic" votes along with a few other changes which I can't remember right now.

This means that changes made on the main code line aren't reflected on Area 51 and vice versa.

Comment: this is an interesting answer because it's very much a developer answer, if you don't mind me saying so! Zooming out of the code, what is the *reason* from a **user point of view**? Or is it simply, as your answer implies, that this was overlooked?

Comment: @Wikis - I suppose I am saying that it was overlooked *because* it's on a different code base.

Comment: thanks. So I guess I should accept this and enter a new question for a feature request - or perhaps a bug report?

Comment: OK, I'll accept this and enter a new question. Thanks for the answer.