# Area 51 should also display up and down votes per person

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, voting, profile-page

I already asked [Why can't you see up and down votes per person at Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75263/why-cant-you-see-up-and-down-votes-per-person-at-area-51)

The answer was that it was *"overlooked"* (see ChrisF's comment below his answer).

That being the case, should it be added?

At the moment there is no way of knowing who is downvoting on Area 51 and there seems to be a lot of it without reason, or at least without explanation. This might reduce that a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total up and down votes can now be viewed on Area 51 profiles for the proposal and discussion sites.

Votes cast in a month, week and day aren't shown, unlike the rest of the network.